# Finding $\lim_{n\to + \infty }(1+\frac{in}{n^2-1})^2$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, limits, complex-numbers

Finding $$\lim_{n\to + \infty }\left(1+\frac{in}{n^2-1}\right)^2$$

I am having troubles with complex limits, and if anyone knows a workbook with solutions online that I can find, it would be very appreciated. :)

Comment: What is $i$ in this case?

Comment: $i^2=-1$, the imaginary unit.

Comment: Ok, see my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

complex limits is actually very similar to the case for real numbers.

Just expand $$(1+\frac{in}{n^2-1})^2=1+\frac{2in}{n^2-1} - \frac{n^2}{(n^2-1)^2}$$

You just need to treat $i$ as a constant, and you will get your desired limit.

Comment: then the limit seems to be $=1$ am I right? Because $\lim_{n\to + \infty} \frac{2in}{n^2-1}=0$ and also the last fraction?

Comment: It seems too easy this way.

Comment: It is this easy. :)

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(1+\frac{in}{n^2-1}\right)^2=$$
$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(1+\frac{in}{n^2-1}\right)\right)^2=$$
$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty }1+i\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\frac{n}{n^2-1}\right)\right)^2=$$

---

Since $n$ grows asymptotically slower than $n^2-1$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2-1}=0$:

---

$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty }1+i\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\frac{1}{n-\frac{1}{n}}\right)\right)^2=$$
$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty }1+i\cdot 0\right)^2=$$
$$\left(1+i\cdot 0\right)^2=$$
$$\left(1+0\right)^2=$$
$$\left(1\right)^2=$$
$$1$$